# spring boot union all not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where i want to combine two tables having the same column's Table1 is having company1 Employee details and table2 is having company2 employee details,EMPID is the primary key in both the table ,My query is

```
select * from table1 t1 where t1.empid=400 union all 
select * from table2 t2 where t2.empid=400
```

In the scenario both the company has one employee with empid=400

I want to get from both the company empid with 400,this query is working fine in postgres sql editor ,but in spring boot when this query is provided ,total 2 rows are returned ,but the two rows are same(as in t1),t2 values are replaced with t1.

can any one provide solution for this or any alternative approach to achieve this in spring boot.

For more understanding

```
@Query(value = "select * from table1 t1 where t1.empid=?1 union all 
select * from table2 t2 where t2.empid=?1 ", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Emp> getByProjectId(@Param("empid") Integer pEmpid);


T1
EMPID   NAME    DEPT
400     test    DEV 
T2
EMPID   NAME    DEPT
400     test2  TESTING


Expected result 

EMPID   NAME    DEPT
400     test    DEV
400     test2   TESTING
```

But spring jpa gives output given as

```
EMPID   NAME    DEPT
400     test    DEV
400     test    DEV
```

EMP entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP")
public class Emp {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMP_NO")
    private int empNo;
    @Column(name = "EMP_NAME")
    private String empName;
    @Column(name = "DEPT_NAME")
    private String deptName;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide the Spring Boot code for handling this?

Comment: Your query includes just table `table1`... So why should it return data from 2 tables?

Comment: sorry it was typo error now i have provided my scenario in a clear way

Comment: Post your `Emp` entity.

Comment: Entity class is provided

Comment: I doubt that that is your full entity...

Comment: Can you check instead of select * try to return specific column of a intend table to see that works?

Comment: what is `table1` and `table2` tables?